# Android Import eclipse project into Android Studio shows an "error some files are crunched"

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to import android **eclipse** project contains library into **Android Studio** .

After importing all library files comes in build.gradle

```
compile files('libs/comscore.jar')
compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-5.3.0.jar')
compile files('libs/json-simple.jar')
```

But shows an **Gradle Build Error**

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':mMHealth:mergeDebugResources'.
 > Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
```

Also shows error that

```
AAPT err(Facade for 2088335535): ERROR: 9-patch image C:\Project\me\src\Health\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\ic_mail.9.png malformed.
AAPT err(Facade for 2034746927): ERROR: 9-patch image C:\Project\me\src\Health\src\main\res\drawable\baby_spinner.9.png malformed.
AAPT err(Facade for 2088335535): No marked region found along edge.
AAPT err(Facade for 2034746927): Must have one-pixel frame that is either transparent or white.
AAPT err(Facade for 2088335535): Found along top edge.
```

My Grdle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
}
}
```

Can anyone please help to solve the gradle.build error

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of error comes when you have png(s) images in your eclipse project,
try to remove these png files and recreate it with photo editor tools

```
9-patch image C:\Project\me\src\Health\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\ic_mail.9.png malformed.

9-patch image C:\Project\me\src\Health\src\main\res\drawable\baby_spinner.9.png malformed.
```

Comment: you mean change the ic_mail.9.png to ic_mail.png @Yasir Ameen

Comment: yes change it, otherwise recreate same image with any photo editor tool